# Default RGB color code for activity backgrounds

Tags: android, background-color, rgb

I am adding pictures to my Android project and the background color of those pictures are the darkest of the darkest color (RGB: 0, 0, 0) but I can see the background color of the images is different from the background color of the android activities.

What is the default RGB color code for the activity backgrounds or is there a method to get it?

(Yes, I know that I could change the background color of the activities to the desired color instead, but that would require that I change all my activities' background color)

Comment: But changing the background of all activities is pretty trivial, look into styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Warpzit recommended I looked into styles and the following solved my problem:

Create an XML file in "values" folder with the following code inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="BackgroundStyle" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
        <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In each layout XML file add the following inside the LinearLayout tag:

```
style="@style/BackgroundStyle"
```